# GraphQL Schema Connection for a list in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm using `createSchemaCustomization` in `gatsby-node` to create schema connections. This works great for things like this:

```
type BoxesYaml implements Node {
  products: [Product] @link(by: "id")
}
```

where `Product` is a type, and `BoxesYaml` has a `product` array containing `product` IDs as part of the YAML.

Now, I'd like to do the same for a YAML file which contains ***only*** a sequence. For example:

```
- product1
- product2
- product3
```

Is it possible to connect these IDs to a `Product` type in Gatsby?

I have tried various attempts at defining the array of products at `Products` but so far have only been able to generate syntax errors.

Something along the lines of

```
type BoxesYaml implements [Product] @link(by: "id")
```